# Can quantum tunneling of some sort allow 2 solids which dont touch each other to have the same chemical potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, quantum-tunneling, chemical-potential

Suppose we have 2 solids seperated by a distance x.If the distance x is in the quantum range(10-20 atoms) even though the solids dont touch each other would their Fermi levels become the same after some time?

Comment: I guess so. But assuming vacuum is a perfect insulator, isn't the the tunneling probability for any finite separation of the two solids zero?